# CardviewHolder and RecycleViewholder android Studio

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I am having problems in implementing this Adapter method. The error is saying cannot resolve `TrendsViewHolder` Symbol.

Can someone please help me understand the issues with this error. Thanks!

[image: 1]

Comment: Send your code as text not a link to a photo please

Answer (score 0):

because you should use trendsActivity.TrendsViewHolder

Comment: I tired the change you told me it didnt work. Now i am getting errors on my create method.

Comment: can you post a screen shot or the error message you are getting